「今日伺うお店」translated as "go-to restuarant"
I was recently watching a video by Akane San and as she was approaching a dumpling restaurant she described it as follows:
"こちらが今日伺うお店です".
It seems the direct translation is something along the lines of: "this is the restaurant i will visit today."
(I am quite new to N3 words so please tell me if this is incorrect)
However, the captions (which are not auto translated through Youtube) translated it as "this is my go-to restaurant". I was confused why an extra level of familiarity was added in this translation, is it a nuance of the word "伺う" or did the translator just assume that Akane has been to the restaurant before? Here's the video if you want a full look at it.
Specifically, I am asking if using 伺う in the context of visiting somewhere will give the impression that you have already been there before.

Akane's being respectful toward the restaurant.  She's very careful about where she films and what she posts.  The proprietors do consent to being filmed or having their businesses included in her videos.  (She's talked about this in previous videos she's done.)  I would imagine that she wants the proprietors to feel respected if they happen to watch her videos, so she's going to use a certain level of polite language.
I think the English subtitles are wrong.  Perhaps the person who added "go-to" misunderstood what this English phrase means.  From the Japanese, there is no sense that this is a place that she regularly visits.  The translator perhaps thought that "go-to" meant the same thing as "where I am going"?
伺う here is just a polite and respectful way of speaking about a business you're visiting or visited.  There is no implication that you've been there before in using this.
I've now listened to the entire video.  It would seem she has not been to restaurant before.  I gather this from what she tells us about the history of the restaurant (which she seemed not to have known); the fact she had to ask whether she pays at the table or at the front counter; and the fact that she wasn't sure whether they only accept cash or not.

thank you for your very detailed answer! It’s good to know that 伺う is more polite than 見に行く or something similar. It seems Akane responds to a lot of the comments on her videos, so i’ll leave a comment about this translation and keep you updated! i’m curious if it’ll be changed or not, even if it’s quite inconsequential.
